# add contact is not present on mobile in diaspora

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, diaspora

I have a working diaspora pod on heroku everything is working cool except when users log in from there mobile device they cant add any one onto there aspects because the add contact option is not there on the mobile site.Does anyone know how to fix it..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/pull/5594

Please also see https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/How_we_communicate, StackOverflow is really not the right place for this kind of question.

Comment: I didn't mean you should update, wait for the release. Don't run develop if you have no clue of what you're doing and can't debug (or even properly report) errors like this.

Comment: Thanks @Jonne Haß eagerly waiting for the next release